# Passing dynamic Type at runtime in Array.ConvertAll

Tags: .net, .net-core

Is it possible to pass Dynamic Type in Array.ConvertAll? in the below code instead of Int32.Parse I tried passing or is there any other way to convert my array of values to another data type

```
var criteria = Array.ConvertAll(filter.Value, Int32.Parse);

MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.Name);
var propertyType = ((PropertyInfo)member.Member).PropertyType;

var criteria = Array.ConvertAll(filter.Value, propertyType); // Gives error
```

Comment: Array.ConvertAll has no value-added and is just there for compatibility I guess: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.cs#L832 it's just a straightforward foreach loop that you can replace that by any direct code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert type from an array but we want to determine the type in runtime.

we can try to use  `Convert.ChangeType` method in the second parameter from `Array.ConvertAll`

```
var criteria = Array.ConvertAll(arr, (o)=> Convert.ChangeType(o,propertyType));
```

Comment: oh my.. i was struggling on this for the past 2 days. Thank you so much!